# Node child process spawn output is different than from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, child-process

When I run the code below, I don't get the same output to the console as I see if I run this command directly via terminal. Any idea on why? Is there another function beyond `stdout.on('data')` that spits out more information?

Specifically, when I run it via terminal, I get a progress bar of sorts indicating a percentage of command completion. When I run it via node, it spits out some of the earlier similar information, then stops for a while until the command is complete.

```
var sh = spawn('sh', ['app/scripts/scriptA.sh', path]);

sh.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `stderr` stream gets flow controlled and that jams things up?  Perhaps add a `sh.stderr.on('data', ...)` handler too.

Comment: Also, the main difference between running it the way you are and running it on the command line is that when running the command line, you are running in a shell, but when running it your way, you are not.  That could lead to some different behaviors.  You can tell the spawn to run it in a shell if you want.

Comment: Did you figure out why the output was different?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of differences.

It could be that you're missing things on `stderr` (`sh.stderr.on('data', ...)`).

The other possibility, especially if it is a progress bar-like thing which is rewriting the line, then `console.log()` won't be able to do that.

How those progress bars work is they use a combination of `process.stdout.write()` and, `process.stdout.cursorTo()` and `process.stdout.clearLine()`,  which actually lets them erase and rewrite a line. Putting that through `console.log` from `data` will output very differently.